# Question Migration?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, migration

The question https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/7366/do-futures-have-predictive-value is showing on our board, but with a note that it's been migrated. When I click on it to respond, it's still loaded at quant.se

It seems to be in SE limbo, not sure if something got stuck here.

Comment: For info: while http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/20841/do-futures-have-predictive-value has a redirect, http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/20841/do-futures-have-predictive-value?noredirect=1 *does not*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The system is working as designed.  The entry remains in our list of questions, since it started life here, but now that the question has been migrated to elsewhere, there is a redirect in place to the question's new home (at the quant SE.)

Comment: sorry, I was confused. Now I see it was migrated away from SE.

Comment: No problem.  (BTW, since you appreciate precise meaning: writing just "SE" to refer to *our* site here is ambiguous. SE is the whole *network* of Stack Exchange sites, us ("Money SE") and Quant SE included, all those others in the site footer, and more.)

Comment: LOL. Yes, I think I used SE lingo correctly (given my own confusion) in the question, but my comment should have been more clear. Yes, I like precision. Thanks again.